# Can Silverlight store data on a user's local machine? Other options to do this?

Tags: database, silverlight

Can Silverlight store data on a user's local machine if correct permissions are enabled?

I have an application where sales reps go to various customers and record their details.
The sales rep does not have internet access.
So I was thinking a Silverlight app would be a good idea as a Windows app is less flexible if we ever need this to be a server based solution in the long run.

I have never used Silverlight so don't know if it can store data locally.
HTML5 client side persistence might also be an idea, not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use isolated storage:

http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/16/tip-of-the-day-19-using-isolated-storage.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(v=VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Siaqodb](http://siaqodb.com) and store data on MyDocuments or other My... folder in OOB mode or in IsolatedStorage

Answer (score 0):

A Windows app is no less flexible than a Silverlight app in yuour scenario.

But yes, you can save locally. Use isolatedstorage if you'd like, allow the user to save using the file dialog, or use elevated permissions to write to My Documents folder (out of browser only)

Pete

Answer (score 0):

yes we can store the silverlightdata into database. but we cannot store the silverlight data directly into the database,we can stored the data through webservices or wcf using proxy class.